# How to hide site membership option for site owner/admin in liferay

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I have created a separate module for creating and assigning users for site admin/owners. So I don't want to show the "Site Membership" option under Users tab for both Site admin and owner.

- How can I hide the Site Membership option?
- Is there any way that the permission or configuration will do the
  required change? Or do I need to create the hook?

Any suggestions please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than changing the semantics of Liferay's built-in roles, rather introduce your own custom roles and define the permissions that you want them to have. Create a "site role", choose "Define Permissions" and add what you need.

From your comment I understand that you *want* to use Site Admin, just not with everything this role comes with. It sounds strange to me that you're demanding a certain solution and favor one that doesn't work, but so be it.

You can check if it's possible to remove some permissions from the "Site Admin" role, but I'd expect a very hard-to-maintain-system resulting from this. Liferay has no means of "maintaining only the users that a certain Administrator has created". What you can do is: An Organization Administrator can administer all users in the organizations they're administering. This might be another solution for you.

Or alternatively, implement your own UI and do your custom (non-Liferay-based) permission checks in it. This UI will then enable your custom admins to administer the users that the UI provides for them.

But if you're stuck to a certain solution, you might be out of luck. Give us more details of your problem and we might come up with a solution unless you insist that your solution is the way to go.

Comment: Opps..sorry Vinod. I totally guided you in the wrong direction. Suggestion  by @Olaf is the correct way, if you didn't go too far for development, from where you can't go back.

Comment: I tried that. But the problem is I want to create the users by site admin. If I give user creation permission for my custom role then the use(Site Admin) is able to view all the users. But I don't want that. I need to Site admin can only view the users which is created by him. So i have created a new module which has user creation permission and able to see only his users. So now I need to hide the existing Site Membership option

Comment: @Olaf Kock any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With Permissions, no you can't. You can't change the permissions of the LR default role by UI at least.

You might have to go with hook or ext. One other way around is to do it with the theme. You might have to hook into Liferay's control panel theme.

Comment: Can you please give me some references (necessary steps) to do it with hook.